# spl autoload register error

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I'm writing some classes that I want to load using the `spl_autoloader_register()` function. I've created a file named autoloader.php and I've saved it inside the folder where I'm saving all the classes needed for my project.
So, to verify if it work, I've loaded it using `require_once` inside a test php page, but unfortunately the console log show me an error output `PHP Warning:  include_once(lib\DataManager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

The test file is inside the same folder who host all the classes, is this error because of this motivation?

Here is the autoloader code

```
<?php 
function autoloader($className){
    include_once($className . '.php');
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

?>
```

and here is how I tried to instantiate it from the test page

```
<?php

require_once 'autoloader.php';
require_once 'config.php';

use lib\DataManager as DataManager;

$dataManager = new DataManager($db);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths are not processed relative to the file where they are written, but rather the "current working directory" of the PHP process (often, the document root of your web process, but not worth relying on).

To reference the location of the current source file, PHP provides two [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

- `__FILE__` is the fully-qualified filename of whatever source file you write it in
- `__DIR__` is the directory containing that file

So, assuming your classes are in the same directory as the definition of your autoloader function, you can write this:

```
function autoloader($className){
    include_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $className . '.php';
}
```

The `__DIR__` is resolved once, when the function is compiled, so whenever this function is run, it will always refer to *the directory where this function was defined*, regardless of where it was called from, or how the script is run.

(Note that `include`, `require`, `include_once`, and `require_once` are keywords not functions, and don't need brackets around them. It won't hurt to add them in general, but can cause confusion in some cases, so is best avoided.)

Comment: I already tryed with the `__DIR__` but I got the same error `PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiraMVC/u/lib/lib\DataManager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.8/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiraMVC/u/lib/autoloader.php on line 3
[25-Jun-2018 19:20:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'lib\DataManager' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiraMVC/u/lib/demo.php:11`

Comment: @user9741470 So, what is the correct path? The first rule of debugging is *always* break the problem down: try to write a line with `echo` that displays the correct full path, using whatever [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) help you. Then put that next to `include_once`.

Comment: The correct path is `kiraMVC/u/lib/` but the autoloader won't find the files inside te lib folder

Comment: @user9741470 Read the error message carefully. Is `'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiraMVC/u/lib/lib\DataManager.php'` the correct file path, or not?

Comment: since the autoloader is in the same folder of the test file, it will load the last folder of the classes path that is lib. so in the error message when I've added the `__DIR_` it will add two times the final folder of the required script. If i remove it, it will look inside the folder but it won't load the classes. I assume that this is because it can't load the right path.

Comment: @user9741470 Again, break the problem down. You have two strings: a directory name, which you can know by writing `echo __DIR__;`, and a class name, which you can check by writing `echo $className;`. Now throw away all your code and write a PHP file with nothing but those two strings, and play with string functions until it echoes the path where you know that class is defined; don't think about loading, or relative paths, just make that string. As soon as you've done that, the logic for your autoloader will become obvious; if it breaks for a different case, repeat the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right. The problem is because it's not pointing to the correct local filesystem to find the file. The following autoloader will work with a relative plugin model, and a library folder model. This will assume the on your configuration file you have defined a variable `$GLOBALS['config']->lib` that defines a filesystem folder that could contains extra system libraries. Of course, this could defined differently, it depends of the application.

```
<?php 
function autoloader($className){
    $paths=[getcwd(),$GLOBALS['config']->lib];
    foreach($paths as $p){
        $filename = str_replace('\\','/',$p.'/'.$className.'.php');
        if (is_readable($filename)) {
            require_once($filename);
            return;
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
?>
```

This will work taking on consideration two scenarios, class is relative to the last requested script, if not tries a predefined folder with classes. Once it's found and loaded it should return, to avoid keep trying loading other paths.

On the array more paths to try could be defined, but try to keep it no more of four paths for performance reasons. Also the order of the paths are the priority where to look first.

This script should work on PHP 5.4 up.

Comment: I'm new to this advanced concept of PHP so I'm very glad for your help. For now I'm testing the autoload function inside the same folder, but as i can understand I need to adapt it to work also if I want to use it from another folder of my project, is this right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "relative to the last requested file". The `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` constants represent the file and directory *where they are used*, and are not affected by anything else in the program.

Comment: @Carlos H I've tried but it will generate the same error. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with namesapces?

Comment: @user9741470 This works assuming that your class is relative to the script that you request. Is this a web application or a CLI application? Normally, on my projects, I create a "library" folder where I put all my classes, this model is good for fixed applications. However, the relative model of execution is useful for the plugin model.

Comment: The class will work for a normal web app. The path of the classes will be u/lib/classes.php so now I have the problem that the autoloader will look inside the lib folder and doesn't find the class files needed, but they are all in that path. In future I want to use autoload from the front controller so I want to solve this issue and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer to a more generic answer. This works from PHP 5.4 up. It Includes 2 paths options, but could be adjusted to include more paths.

Comment: To test if the problem was with the autoloader or with the namespaces, I've moved out from the classes folder the `autoload.php` file. Now it works, but I can't figure out whats was the problem.

Comment: If you noticed from my code I get rid off the `__FILE__` and instead I'm using `getcwd()` instead. This should allow the autoloader to be anywhere else, but it will depends of the path of the entry point script. I will not recommend it 100% but you could alter your current working directory using `chdir()`.